# Toad: queries almost alike, one finishes fast, other one doesn't finish at all

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am using Toad to query an Oracle database.

I have two (complex) queries that are completely the same, only difference is in the where clause. I can not shown them due to privacy at my job.

Query 1: a part of the where clauses states : where account is in (1,2,3,4,5) (these are dummy numbers) : this query finished fast (2 minutes 30 seconds)

Query 2: that same part of the where clause states: where account is in (1,2,3) : this query never finishes.

Apart from the above, the queries are completely the same. They do however comprise of a lot of other joins and conditions. All the same.

I don't get what is going on here, I would think query 2 needs to finish faster since it doesn't have '4' or '5' in its clause.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the execution plan for both queries : 
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgsql/generating-and-displaying-execution-plans.html#GUID-60E30B1C-342B-4D71-B154-C26623D6A3B1

Comment: Look at the execution plans for the two queries to see what's different. If the values are hard-coded then they will get different plans anyway, and if they were parsed at different times they might be based on different stats. But the plans will show you what is going on, hopefully.

Comment: I checked it. The query that doesn't run, uses nested loop as join. The query that does run, uses hash join. So that probably explains the difference. Any way I can make the execution of the query smarter?